# Transparent but outlined layer in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, mapping, color, transparency-opacity, fill

My original code creates red boxes over my study area:

```
Map.addLayer(geometry, {color: 'FF0000'});
```

I would like for these boxes to have a transparent fill and clear borders. I have tried this based on a post I saw on here:

```
Map.addLayer(geometry, {color: 'FF0000',
  'width': 2,
  'lineType': 'solid',
  'fillColor': '00000000',
  });
```

This didn't change anything for me even though it worked for the other person (https://github.com/gee-community/geemap/discussions/262).

I've tried removing the first color:

```
Map.addLayer(geometry, {
  'width': 2,
  'lineType': 'solid',
  'fillColor': '00000000',
  });
```

Which gave me a slightly transparent black box. But I want it full transparent.

Comment: Which language do you use, JavaScript or Python?

Answer (score 1):

Since your aim is for visualization purposes, it would be better to make an `ee.FeatureCollection` from the geometry to set a transparent fill color. Therefore, define the `fillColor` property on the `ee.FeatureCollection` object instead of in the visualization parameters. You should use `style` function for this.

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [[[26.61, 41.63],
    [26.61, 37.22],
    [38.39, 37.22],
    [38.39, 41.63]]]
);
          
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection(geometry).style({fillColor:'00000000'})

Map.addLayer(fc, {}, "Transparent Vector")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Kadir Sahbaz, that worked!